# Jquery Jquery-UI Range Slider .each(function(){}); not works fine and slowly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, each, rangeslider

I want to write a jquery function, that finds every .arti-carousel-ui-slider div and create a jquery ui range slider. It works not realy fine. The second slider object works fine, but in the first the slider didn`t change the values.

Here the CODE:

```
<div class="column col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12"> //PHP Code First Element
<div class="arti-carousel-ui-slider">
<label for="arti_carousel_tab_items_distance">'.__('Distance Carousel-Items', 'arti-carousel').'</label>
<input type="hidden" name="arti_carousel_tab_items_distance" value="'.esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'arti_carousel_tab_items_distance', true)).'">
<div class="arti-carousel-ui-slider-slidebar" data-value="20" data-max="120" data-step="5"></div>
<p>'.__('The space between the Carousel-Items in px: ', 'arti-carousel').'<span class="slider-value"></span></p>
</div>                                    
</div> 

<div class="column col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12"> //PHP Code Second Element
<div class="arti-carousel-ui-slider">
<label for="arti_carousel_tab_formattings_items_headline_fontsize">'.__('Headline Font-Size Carousel Item', 'arti-carousel').'</label>
<input type="hidden" name="arti_carousel_tab_formattings_items_headline_fontsize" value="'.esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'arti_carousel_tab_formattings_items_headline_fontsize', true)).'">
<div class="arti-carousel-ui-slider-slidebar" data-value="18" data-max="50" data-step="1"></div>
<p>'.__('The Font-Size is set to: ', 'arti-carousel').'<span class="slider-value"></span></p>
</div>
</div>


//JavaScript Code
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var countslide = 0;
 $(".arti-carousel-ui-slider").each(function(){
        countslide = countslide + 1;
        $(this).attr("data-id",countslide);
        $(this).find( '.slider-value' ).attr("data-id",countslide);
        $(this).find('.arti-carousel-ui-slider-slidebar').attr("data-id",countslide);
        $('.arti-carousel-ui-slider-slidebar[data-id='+countslide+']').slider(
            {
                value:$('.arti-carousel-ui-slider-slidebar[data-id='+countslide+']').attr("data-value"),
                min: 0,
                max: $('.arti-carousel-ui-slider-slidebar[data-id='+countslide+']').attr("data-max"),
                step: $('.arti-carousel-ui-slider-slidebar[data-id='+countslide+']').attr("data-step"),
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( '.slider-value[data-id='+countslide+']' ).html( ui.value+'px' ),
                    $( '.arti-carousel-ui-slider[data-id='+countslide+'] input' ).val(ui.value+'px')
                }
            }
        );
        $(this).find( '.slider-value[data-id='+countslide+']').html(  $('.arti-carousel-ui-slider-slidebar[data-id='+countslide+']').slider('value')+'px' );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
$('.arti-carousel-ui-slider-slidebar[data-id='+countslide+']').slider(
        {
            value:$('.arti-carousel-ui-slider-slidebar[data-id='+countslide+']').attr("data-value"),
            min: 0,
            max: $('.arti-carousel-ui-slider-slidebar[data-id='+countslide+']').attr("data-max"),
            step: $('.arti-carousel-ui-slider-slidebar[data-id='+countslide+']').attr("data-step"),
            slide: function( event, ui ) {

                $(this).parent().find('.slider-value').html( ui.value+'px' ),
                $(this).parent().find('input' ).val(ui.value+'px')

            }
        }
    );
```